# java split datetime period and return array

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, split

I'm building a web application in java using simple jsp, I'd like to know if there is a way to get an array of `datetime` values between `datetime_start` and datetime_stop per `hours/day/minutes/etc`. 
I'm searching for something like that:

```
Array getvalues(datetime_start, datetime_stop, "day/hours/min")
```

for example:

```
getvalues("2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812","2018-07-03 20:25:08.208812","hours");
```

it returns:

```
2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812 <br>
2018-07-02 21:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 22:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 23:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 24:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 01:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 02:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 03:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 04:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 05:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 06:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 07:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 08:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 09:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 10:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 11:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 12:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 13:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 14:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 15:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 16:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 17:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 18:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 19:25:08.208812<br>
2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812<br>
```

can enyone help me?

Comment: You want a `String` Array to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

With `java.time`, you can implement your own way of doing that. A simple example to get you started could be:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
final LocalDateTime dateFirst = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812", formatter);
final LocalDateTime dateLast = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-07-03 20:25:08.208812", formatter);

final ChronoUnit unit = ChronoUnit.valueOf("HOURS");

final List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (LocalDateTime dateBetween = dateFirst; !dateBetween.isAfter(dateLast); dateBetween = dateBetween.plus(Duration.of(1, unit))) {
    dates.add(dateBetween.format(formatter));
}

System.out.println(dates);
```

As you can see, you can add some customization:

- the date format, since `LocalDateTime` expects a `T` rather than a whitespace between the date and time. You can implement your own formatter and give it to `LocalDateTime#parse` if you wish to keep your format
- you can get the unit type dynamically but you should provide it in all caps
- I made a list but you can easily convert it to an array (with `dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()])`), or use `unit.between(dateFirst, dateLast)` to know in advance the size of the array if you wish to do other things with it while you build the array.

With this you can make your own method which follows your API and logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to get the result that you want. You may want to add more checks, e.g., input validity check and handling.

**The utility class that contains the main logic:**

```
public class PeriodicDateTimeProducer {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    public List<LocalDateTime> getPeriodicDateTime(String start, String end, PeriodMeasure measure){
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(start, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(end, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

        List<LocalDateTime> results = new ArrayList<>();

        // Use isAfter instead of isBefore becoz you want to include the endDateTime, if it's a valid result
        while(!startDateTime.isAfter(endDateTime)){
            results.add(startDateTime);
            startDateTime = startDateTime.plus(1, measure.getChronoUnit());
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

**The enum that helps you to restrict what units can be used. It also helps to reduce errors caused by typos:**

```
public enum PeriodMeasure{
    DAY(ChronoUnit.DAYS),
    HOUR(ChronoUnit.HOURS),
    MINUTE(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

    PeriodMeasure(ChronoUnit unit){
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    private ChronoUnit unit;

    public ChronoUnit getChronoUnit(){
        return this.unit;
    }
}
```

**The tester class:**

```
public class TestPeriodicDateTime {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    public static void main (String... args){
        PeriodicDateTimeProducer dateTimeUtil = new PeriodicDateTimeProducer();

        List<LocalDateTime> rst = dateTimeUtil.getPeriodicDateTime("2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812", "2018-07-03 20:25:08.208812", PeriodMeasure.HOUR);

        rst.forEach(r -> System.out.println(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(r)));
    }
}
```

The result:

```
2018-07-02 20:25:08.208812
2018-07-02 21:25:08.208812
2018-07-02 22:25:08.208812
2018-07-02 23:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 00:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 01:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 02:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 03:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 04:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 05:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 06:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 07:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 08:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 09:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 10:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 11:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 12:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 13:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 14:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 15:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 16:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 17:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 18:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 19:25:08.208812
2018-07-03 20:25:08.208812

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Main ideas in this solution:

1. Use *DateTimeFormatter* to specify the format that you desire;
2. *LocalDateTime.isBefore()* will return false for same *LocalDateTime*, so you should use *!isAfter()* if you want to include *endDateTime*, if it's a valid result;
3. Use constant (*static final*) formatter to coerce users of the function to use specific format. However, should you desire a solution which supports variable *DateTimeFormatter*, you can also do it by making the formmater attribute non-constant (or simply add it as a parameter of the method, which may NOT be desired as you would end up with too many args);
4. Use a enum to control the set of *ChronoUnit* allowed for the period. This will not only enforce cleaner and more manageable code, but also give you more control over the logic and thus less error-prone;

Comment: Updated the post: 1). refactored the class name from **PeriodicDateTimeUtil** to **PeriodicDateTimeProducer**, as I feel _Util_ classes are better suited with **static** methods; 2). explained some ideas behind the implementation, first 2 points are about the logic, latter 2 are about code style (best practices).